# Oracle to MySql PHP equivalency

Tags: php, mysql

How would you rewrite the following code so that it works for MySQL as opposed to Oracle databases?

```
try
{
    $connect = odbc_connect("Database","user","password");

    $sql = "UPDATE Table SET " . $_POST['field'] . "='" . $_POST['value'] . "' WHERE EmployeeID = " . $_POST['eid'];

    odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Failed: <br>" + $e->getMessage();
}
```

The closest I can think of is this:

```
try
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password'); 
        mysqli_select_db( $connection, 'database');

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                  //list all results here in variables
}

        $sql = "UPDATE grooming SET " . $_POST['field'] . "='" . $_POST['value'] . "' WHERE ID = " . $_POST['ID'];

    mysqli_execute($sql);  //I am aware this is deprecated but I can't find anything similar


}
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Failed: <br>" + $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: You don't use EITHER option. You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and are just begging to get your server pwn3d. And then you rip out that "fetch" business. Why are you fetching from a result which doesn't exist?

Comment: Agreed.  Learn about prepared statements.  They're actually easier overall, and can help prevent a lot of boneheaded mistakes.

Comment: This is actually for a class where the code we're using isn't all that great.  If this were a more "real world" application, I would totally put that under consideration.

Comment: As someone relatively new to this language, I agree, but I have to work with what I'm given.